Conflict between tabColor and protection with openpyxl
It seems I can't have a tabColor with a protection…
Un-commenting the lines linked to protection unsets the tab color.
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for _r_ in range(1,4):
    ws.cell(row=_r_, column=1, value=_r_)


ws_prop = ws.sheet_properties
ws_prop.tabColor = "FF7400"

#ws.protection.sheet = True
#ws.protection.set_password("aze", already_hashed=False)
#wb.security.set_workbook_password("aze", already_hashed=False)
#wb.security.lockStructure = True

wb.save("output_formatted.xlsx")

Any help appreciated.

The TAB colour is set regardless, so maybe more the app than the implementation.

Excel and WPS Office don't exhibit the issue, only LibreOffice...
